# Node.js File extraction module for both zip and rar?

Tags: node.js, node-modules, compression

I am working on a node.js project which involves file extraction of multiple formats (zip, rar and potentially more). I have tried a few node modules to extract rar file like node-unrar, but none of them handles the job perfectly, not to say to handle extraction for both zip and rar. I am wondering if there is some wrapper module that handles extraction of multiple formats, or if not then what is the best (most robust and easy-to-use) node module for handling rar file extraction.

Comment: try zlib modules works fine for zip.

Comment: Thanks for your response but as I mentioned in the description, I am actually not that worried about de-compressing zip files. I want to find a wrapper that can handle both formats or a really good RAR file de-compressor.

Comment: Try one of these: [all-unpacker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/all-unpacker), [unpack-all](https://www.npmjs.com/package/unpack-all) . Recommendation question are likely to be closed though..

Answer (score 2):

## RAR

[unrar-promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/unrar-promise)

```
 const unrarp = require('unrar-promise');   
      unrarp
      .extractAll('rar-file-path', 'extract-directory')
      .then(result => {
        cb(null, result);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        cb(err);
      });
```

### 7z ( npm unzip have unreadable code(zip file name encoding is gbk/gb2312))

[7zip-min](https://github.com/onikienko/7zip-min)

> 7za.exe supports only 7z, lzma, cab, zip, gzip, bzip2, Z and tar
>   formats.

```
   const _7z = require('7zip-min');
    _7z.unpack('zip-7z-file-path', 'extract-directory', err => {
      if (err) {
        return cb(err);
      }
      cb(null, 'extract-directory');
    });
```